# How to use ofType with more than 5 actions?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have to use ofType with more than 5 actions in my effect.

```
@Effect()
  applyInspectionsFilters$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(
      InspectionsPageActions.applyInspectionsFilters.type,
      InspectionsPageActions.clearSelectedInspectionsFilters.type,
      InspectionsPageActions.removeSelectedStatusFilter.type,
      InspectionsPageActions.removeSelectedAttributeFilter.type,
      InspectionsPageActions.removeSelectedUserFilter.type,
      InspectionsPageActions.removeNotAssignedUsersFilter.type
    ),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store$.pipe(select(fromInspections.getSelectedInspectionsFilters))
    ),
    switchMap(([action, filters]) =>
      ...
    )
  );
```

How should I do this when the maximum number of parameters is 5 in their library?

Comment: what are you doing that requires an effect, can't this be done in the reducer?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

docs here: https://ngrx.io/api/effects/ofType

show the way to do it is something like this:

```
ofType(
  ...[InspectionsPageActions.applyInspectionsFilters.type,
  InspectionsPageActions.clearSelectedInspectionsFilters.type,
  InspectionsPageActions.removeSelectedStatusFilter.type,
  InspectionsPageActions.removeSelectedAttributeFilter.type,
  InspectionsPageActions.removeSelectedUserFilter.type,
  InspectionsPageActions.removeNotAssignedUsersFilter.type]
),
```

Comment: It's same to pass  the actions separated by comma

Comment: I dont understand how is this different?

Comment: @Deian the diff is that in older versions of typescript the typings would break after a certain number of parameters because you couldn't just define N generic parameters and the corresponding generic output type, they had to each be defined separately in overload signatures, and ngrx defined out to 5 generic input parameters, beyond that you needed to do this trick to get ts to know what you wanted. it was a work around for a typescript shortcoming basically. but in compiled js, there is no difference in what actually happens

Comment: thank you @bryan60 for elaborating.. so it's technically tsc issue..   I was looking into the code of ofType() and was wondering why they implemented this ways - 5 params, instead they could've  ofType(...actions:ActionCreate[]) ... it seems to me it would've work better